# I want hair particle system to change the color of each hair depending on the direction of sway.

Tags: python, materials, particles, color, hair

Summary:
I want hair particle system to change the color of each hair depending on the direction of sway. I have not programmed anything with blender before but am ok with python if some can guide me if that is required.

More Detail:
I am trying to create a visualisation of a biological system that uses "hair cells". And the particular feature of this system is that when the hairs are bent in a particular direction they send more neurological signals. And when they bend opposite that direction they decrease their neurological signals.

What I hope to do is produce a red (for high activity) to blue (for low activity) map of hairs as they move around attached to the moving surface.

So far I have surfaces with the hair particle system working using "hair dynamics". So the scene is set I just need to dynamically recolor the strands when they bend towards particular directions.

I hope that python is not needed but don't mind if it is.

Thank you for any help you can give.